# Why im getting error on the line InitializeComponent();?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this Usercontrol, I created and Im getting error on `InitializeComponent`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Speech.Synthesis;

namespace RssNews
{
    public partial class
        FeederControl : UserControl
    {
        SpeechSynthesizer speaker;
        Label[] list = new Label[5];
        int jump = 0;
        private IContainer components;

        public string[] NewsTextFeed { get; set; }
        public Color[] TextColor { get; set; }

        private int _spacing = 10;
        public int Spacing
        {
            get { return _spacing; }
            set { _spacing = value; }
        }

        public void NewsFeederControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            speaker = new SpeechSynthesizer();
            Init();
        }
```

The error/s:

> Error 29  The call is ambiguous between the following methods or
>   properties: 'RssNews.FeederControl.InitializeComponent()' and
>   'RssNews.FeederControl.InitializeComponent()'

Then in the designer of the UserControl:

> Error 31  Ambiguity between 'RssNews.FeederControl.components' and
>   'RssNews.FeederControl.components'

This is the designer code:

```
namespace RssNews
{
    partial class FeederControl
    {
        /// <summary> 
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary> 
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Component Designer generated code

        /// <summary> 
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify 
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
            this.timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer(this.components);
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // FeederControl
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.AntiqueWhite;
            this.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
            this.Name = "FeederControl";
            this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(146, 146);
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.FeederControl_Load);
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer1;
    }
}
```

Im getting erorrs same error meassage on all components in the designer.cs code.
And also

> Error 2   Type 'RssNews.FeederControl' already defines a member called
>   'InitializeComponent' with the same parameter types

This control is working good on another project i did same code. I just changed the namespaces names for this project. The one before was mws and this one is RssNews

How can i fix the errors ?

Comment: Sounds like you have *two* Designer.cs source files for the UserControl.  Hard to guess how you did that :)  Delete one of them.  Not calling InitializeComponent() in the constructor is another thing you'll regret, it is not going to work well in the designer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First thing: you have a different constructor name then the class name.
Second, have you tried to debug it? You posted way too much code.
Trim it down to the relevant pieces.

Solution:

You have 2 partials that are merged into one, and the function InitializeComponent() defined twice. You must define it only in one of the two partials. Keep it where VS put it.